# Is there a way to add a listener to an Executor/Future's?

Tags: java, multithreading

Java : Is there a way to add a listener to an [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)?
I have a collection with `Future`s which I try to monitorize , as to update some GUI statuses. Currently I am checking in a background thread if there are differences in the submitted/completed tasks, but I am doing this in a `while(true){}` block and I do not like this approach.

Comment: No; this is one of the stupidest parts of Java.

Comment: What GUI toolkit are you using?

Comment: @Puce: This has nothing to do with GUIs.

Comment: @SLaks `This has nothing to do with GUIs` one of ways how to starting `Workers Thread` (`Concurency` and `MultiThreading` in Swing) from `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread`, slightly agreed implementations of methods could be better ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that.

Instead, use Google's [`ListenableFuture<V>` interface](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html).
Alternatively, use a language with better async support, such as C# and the TPL.

Answer (score 2):

You could use SwingWorkers or similar classes depending on your GUI toolkit to get notified when a task completes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something when the task completes, you add it to the task itself.

```
 public static <T> void addTask(Callable<T> tCall) {
     executor.submit(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             T t = tCall.call();
             // what you want done when the task completes.
             process(t);
         }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService instead of Executor to submit tasks. It has method take() which returns recently completed task. Start additional thread (or SwingWorker) which would call `take()` in a loop, and update GUI status with the result.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to @Peter Lawrey's answer.

I added a listener as a member variable of the callable and called that listener just before the Callable returned its result.

So you have a Listener interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Listener<T> {    
    void notify(T result);    
}
```

A Callable with that as a member variable:

```
public class CallbackCallable implements Callable<String>{

    private Listener<String> listener;

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        // do some stuff
        if (listener != null) 
             listener.notify("result string");
        return "result string";
    }

    public void setListener(Listener<String> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

And in your application you pass an implementation of the listener with what you want to be done with the result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    System.out.println("This is thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    CallbackCallable myCallable = new CallbackCallable();
    myCallable.setListener(r -> {
        // process your callable result here            
        System.out.println("Got from Callable: " + r);
        System.out.println("This is thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    });

    es.submit(myCallable);
}
```

Only thing you need to keep in mind is that your implementation will run on the same thread as the Callable, as you can see if you run that:

```
This is thread: main
Got from Callable: result string
This is thread: pool-1-thread-1
```